# Source Engine: How to find certain animations, textures, etc?

Tags: garrys-mod, source-engine, half-life-2, hammer

As I'm making maps on the Hammer editor, I'm looking for certain animations that I have seen in Half-Life 2. However, to find the exact animation in Hammer is sometimes extremely difficult.

In either HL2, Garry's Mod or somehow Hammer itself, how could I find animations that are playing? This could also relate to entities, models and textures.

One example is I'm looking for the animation of the lady in the trainstation in HL2 where she holds onto the fence (this is near the very beginning). I know exactly what the animation looks like, but I can't find it in Hammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the name of a sequence an NPC is executing in game by using `ent_text`: turn on `sv_cheats 1` and `developer 1`, then point at the NPC and run `ent_text` in the console. One of the values displayed on screen will be `Sequence` which will contain the animation name.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! It tells you a lot about the entity, be it an NPC or otherwise. One thing to point out (as I have found): not all NPC's of a class have the same animations. For example, I found that a certain male citizen does not share the same animations as a certain female citizen.